# Reordering columns in R by type of contents

Tags: r

I have a large data frame that I'm analyzing, but that frame involves columns that are either character, integer, or numeric data. I want to organize the columns in such a way that the character columns all come first, followed by the numeric columns, and finally followed by the integer columns. Is there a way to automate this or do this quickly?

My data frame has ~800 columns and they mostly have long and complicated names

Comment: Please provide some code or test example of what you've done so far.

Answer (score 1):

Use `vapply(DF, typeof, character(1L))` to locate the types. Then, order the columns by position using `which`:

```r
DF <- data.frame(A = letters, 
                 B = 1:26, 
                 C = 1:26 + 5.5, 
                 D = LETTERS,
                 # X = 1:26 > 5, 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
types <- vapply(DF, typeof, character(1L))
`%notin%` <- Negate("%in%")
DF[, c(which(types == "character"), 
       which(types == "double"), 
       which(types == "integer"), 
       which(types %notin% c("character", "double", "integer")))]
#>    A D    C  B
#> 1  a A  6.5  1
#> 2  b B  7.5  2
#> 3  c C  8.5  3
#> 4  d D  9.5  4
#> 5  e E 10.5  5
#> 6  f F 11.5  6
#> 7  g G 12.5  7
#> 8  h H 13.5  8
#> 9  i I 14.5  9
#> 10 j J 15.5 10
#> 11 k K 16.5 11
#> 12 l L 17.5 12
#> 13 m M 18.5 13
#> 14 n N 19.5 14
#> 15 o O 20.5 15
#> 16 p P 21.5 16
#> 17 q Q 22.5 17
#> 18 r R 23.5 18
#> 19 s S 24.5 19
#> 20 t T 25.5 20
#> 21 u U 26.5 21
#> 22 v V 27.5 22
#> 23 w W 28.5 23
#> 24 x X 29.5 24
#> 25 y Y 30.5 25
#> 26 z Z 31.5 26
```

<sup>Created on 2018-06-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).</sup>

The last line can be discarded if you know that there are only character, double, or integer columns, or if only want such columns.

Comment: Good answer. Just a note: with `!types %in% c("character", "double", "integer"))`, no need to define/use `%notin%`